# Better algorithm to change image of a button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm

I have implemented search functionality with a textbox and a button.

When I press enter in the textbox or when the button is clicked, the image that the button loads is changed(i.e the image is now search_next). I want the previous image(search image) to be loaded for the button if the search text changes.

This is what I have done so far.

```
 <Button x:Name="button1" Click="Button_Click">
        <Image Source="..\Images\Search.ico" Height="13" Width="15"></Image>
 </Button>
```

On buttonclick / KeyUp event in the textbox -

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Search_next.ico",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    img.Stretch = Stretch.None;
    button1.Content = img;
}

void searchTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = new Image();
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/FunctionWizardControl;component/Images/Search_next.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        img.Stretch = Stretch.None;
        button1.Content = img;
    } 
}
```

I want the search image to be displayed when the text changes. I thought of adding an else statement to the KeyUp event but doesn't that set the content of the button everytime a user types into the textbox? How do I implement this change?

Comment: Using a binding. When the binding of the `TextBox` changes after the search, set the image again. Otherwise "ignore" the change.

Comment: But that sets the image every time I change the the text right? It's again the same problem.

Comment: I have changed `when I click enter in the TextBox` to `when I press enter in the Textbox` in your question. The former is very confusing.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice.

Answer (score 4):

Using a binding with 2 properties:

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _searchString;
    private string _imageSource;

    public string SearchString
    {
        get { return _searchString; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _searchString) return;
            _searchString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            ImageSource = @"/FunctionWizardControl;component/Images/Search_next.ico";
        }
    }

    public string ImageSource
    {
        get { return _imageSource; }
        set
        {
            // Only change image, if different than before
            if (value == _imageSource) return;
            _imageSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged with method 'OnPropertyChanged'...
}
```

Then in the XAML code, set the correct binding according to your needs (e.g. to `LostFocus` (default), so it doesn't check on every key press:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Click="Button_Click">
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="13" Width="15"/>
</Button>
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchString, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

Comment: you beat me to it. +1

Comment: notice that the `TextBlock` needs to be a `TextBox` for all this to work.